# midnight commander go to root directory shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mc, user-interface

I would like to set "/" key as shortcut for going to root directory in midnight commander. I have tried to find relevant option in /etc/mc/md.default.keymap file but I couldn't. Is there relevant option in midnight commander or maybe there is ability to assign relevant macro under "/" key?

Comment: Use directory hotlist: ctrl-\ . Or simply type `cd /`

Comment: @IporSircer I definitely want "/" shortcut

Comment: then use `xbindkeys`

Comment: xbindkeys? Midnight commander runs at terminal..........